# Counterexample the riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

The exercises shows that the Riesz Representation does not hold on infinite-dimensional inner product spaces. I need help.

Suppose $C_{\mathbb{R}}([-1, 1])$ is the vector space of continuous real-valued functions on the interval  $[-1, 1]$ with inner product given by
\begin{equation}
\langle \ f\ , \ g \ \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x) dx
\end{equation}
for $f, g \in C_{\mathbb{R}}([-1, 1])$. Let $\varphi$ be the linear functional on $C_{\mathbb{R}}([-1, 1])$ defined by $\varphi (f ) = f (0)$. Show that there does not exist $g \in C_{\mathbb{R}}([-1, 1])$ 
such that
\begin{equation}
\varphi(f) = \langle \ f\ , \ g \ \rangle 
\end{equation}
for every $f \in C_{\mathbb{R}}([-1, 1])$.

Comment: Huh?  The Riesz representation theorem for $C(K)'$ says in this case the continuous dual of $C_\mathbb{R}([-1,1])$ is the finite signed Borel measures on $[-1,1]$.  And your "counterexample" isn't a counterexample at all because the Dirac delta is a regular Borel probability measure.  Are you misquoting?

Comment: I need to show that the Riesz represetization theorem is not fulfilled for spaces of infinite dimension and the counterexample I must demonstrate the exercise above.

Comment: I suspect that, by "Riesz representation theorem", you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) (and @user10354138 means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)). The first of these is perfectly valid for infinite dimensions, provided that you are dealing with Hilbert spaces. The latter is exactly the problem in your "counterexample" - it lacks completeness.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

If there is such a $g$, then $\varphi$ is a *continuous* linear functional on the given space, and $\varphi(f) = 0$ if $f(0) = 0$. As the set of all such $f$ is (everywhere) dense in the space, this would imply $\varphi \equiv 0$.

Comment: I have another idea of ​​how to prove it but thank you very much.